# OpenTok audio issue on incoming calls during video conversation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opentok

I found a critical issue during video call in OpenTok when user gets any phone call during conversation and user dismisses/attend the incoming call video remains fine but audio doesn't work. How can I keep audio on incoming calls during video calling in OpenTok.

Any help will be appreciable.